# How to scroll to last div which is dynamically added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added div tag in a file (chat.html (say)) and when we click on the button then I am adding rows dynamically to the div in the script. I have added iframe tag in another file say(list.html) and assigning src attribute to the chat.html. When the page of chat.html gets loaded then it is not going to end of the div unless I need to scroll manually to the end of the div. Instead, it should automatically scroll to the end of the div and also whenever the div gets added it should get the scroll to the div.

```
//list.html page code
<body>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto mt-5">
        <iframe width="1000px" height="650px" src="EarlyChat.html" ></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

//chat.html page code
<section style="padding: 50px 0 0 0">
 <div id="questions" style="margin-bottom: 85px !important;"></div>
   <div class="msg-box">
     <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="input-box sty-one" id="message" placeholder="Enter message"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-2" style="margin-top: 5px" onclick="sendmessage()">send</button> 
     </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

```
function sendmessage(){

     db.collection("ChatRoom").doc(userid).collection("Cities").orderBy("Time")
     .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        var store_row = document.createElement("questions");
        var store;
        $('#questions').empty();
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          typeofmessage = doc.data().SenderId;
                    time = doc.data().Time.toDate();
                    console.log("typeofmessage value is",typeofmessage,time);
                    message = doc.data().message;
                    console.log("messages")
                    store = document.createElement("div");
                    if(typeofmessage == "Df"){
                        // console.log("left")
                        leftids.push(message)
                        console.log("store.getAttributes",store.getAttribute.id)
                        store.setAttribute("class", "card no-border");
                        store.setAttribute("id", doc.id);
                        store.innerHTML = `<div class="container1 darker">
                                        <img src="assets/images/user1.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
                                        <p class="text-left">` + message + `</p>
                                        <span class="time-left">` + time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes()  + `</span>
                                        </div>`;

                    }
                    else if(typeofmessage == userid){
                        console.log("right")
                        rightids.push(message)
                        // store = document.createElement("div");
                        store.setAttribute("class", "card no-border");
                        store.setAttribute("id", doc.id);
                        store.innerHTML = `<div class="container1">
                                        <img src="assets/images/image 209.png" alt="Avatar" class="right" style="width:100%;">
                                        <p class="text-right">` + message + `</p>
                                        <span class="time-right">` + time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + `</span>
                                        </div>`;
                    }
                    store_row.append(store);
                    console.log("storerow.count is",store_row)
                    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = store_row.innerHTML;

                });
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can mention id or name in src attribute to automatically jump to the particular div tag. First you should assign different id for each div tags and then when the button is clicked you should append the id of the last div tag in iframe's src attribute in list.html like below.

```
<iframe width="1000px" height="650px" src="EarlyChat.html#message1" ></iframe> // assuming message1 is id of last div tag.
```

For more information, visit [this link](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html)

Comment: How should I assign different ids for each row because no of div's depend on the documents in the database.

Comment: keep a counter variable( say ctr ). When adding a row assign id="message"+ctr and increment ctr. so for first row it would be message1 and for second row it would be message2 and so on. Now you get different id for each row.

Comment: Ya I did the same but how should I mention it in the iframe tag.

Comment: @sachin- Actually, when u see the code I am assigning document Id as the attribute to the row.

Comment: In that case, you should have constant id for last div tag. say the id of last div tag must be "lastmessage" no matter how many rows are present. If the id of last row remains same, you can mention it in iframe's src attribute like this src="chats.html#lastmessage". After adding all the rows, you must change the id of last row with the help of counter variable.

Comment: I have assigned the constant id for the last message and added it in the iframe but I did not get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window`'s `scrollTo` method and the last div's `offsetTop` property to accomplish this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

I've simplified your example to show it in action. Below, I'm dynamically adding elements, keeping a reference to the last element's `offsetTop`, then scrolling to the elements `offsetTop`

The only caveat is I had to use a `setTimeout` to make sure the new elements have made it onto the DOM.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
    <script>
        // Simulate an array of data to render new content
        const paragraphs = []
        let lastParagraphY = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            paragraphs.push(`This is paragraph ${i}. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`)
        }

        // Dynamically create new html nodes
        paragraphs.forEach((paragraph, index) => {
            const body = document.querySelector('body')
            const newParagraph = document.createElement('p')
            newParagraph.innerHTML = paragraph
            newParagraph.id = index
            body.appendChild(newParagraph)
            lastParagraphY = newParagraph.offsetTop
        })

        // Ensure the dynamic elements have rendered
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.scrollTo(0, lastParagraphY)
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: No it is not getting.